# Look Up field giving issues in searching the bulk uploaded data

Tags: data-loader, search

If anybody has an idea on the below issue, please suggest urgently.
I have updated values on a custom object by data loader/import wizard. Those values has been referred by another look up field " Model description" in another custom object " Quotation".

[image]

Now in the look up search, shows only the uploaded values which has been opened in SF once. If i have not at all open any values its not showing in the search result. I need to manually open the record (may be next time opening SF, it may need the same task, its irritating) and from next time its keep showing. Now I have uploaded 9000 records, so its impossible to manually open each records once to show those in search. Can you please suggest some ways for this issue?

I have tried updated all the records using the developer console. (updated the NAME) which was success, but still same issue.

Comment: Just a basic question.Did you enter the name or some searchable content which you have entered for searching in the lookup and click the magnifying glass?

Comment: When you open lookup dialog, if the record does not appear in the lookup dialog, you can perform a search on the record and select it.

Comment: The search won't be populated until you either A) search for a record specifically or B) have opened it via the search box. This issue can be seen here: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gyoKAAQ. One workaround to quickly search would be to use `*a*`, surrounding a common letter with wildcards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entering atleast three character in the search area and changing it to all field search do worked.